# Calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(10+3\cos n)^n+6^n}{(10+3\cos n)^n+3^n}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(10+3\cos n)^n+6^n}{(10+3\cos n)^n+3^n}$$

My attempt: $1\leq \frac{(10+3\cos n)^n+6^n}{(10+3\cos n)^n+3^n}\leq\frac{(10+3\cos n)^n+6^n}{(10+3\cos n)^n}=1+\frac{6^n}{(10+3\cos n)^n}$

Now I understand that $\frac{6^n}{(10+3\cos n)^n}$ goes to $0$ so by the sandwich theorem I would get that the solution is $1$.
 However I saw in the solution manual that they wrote $1+\frac{6^n}{(10+3\cos n)^n}\leq 1+\frac{6^n}{7^n}$ and then they said $\frac{6^n}{7^n}$ goes to $0$. Can someone explain how they got $7^n$ in the denominator?

Comment: $10+3\cos n\ge 10-3\cdot 1=7$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $-1 \le \cos n \le 1$, hence 
$$ 7 \le 10 + 3\cos n \le 13 $$
Now we get 
$$ 7^n \le (10 + 3\cos n)^n \le 13^n $$
that gives 
$$ \frac 1{7^n} \ge \frac 1{(10 + 3\cos n)^n} $$
and therefore 
$$ \frac {6^n}{(10 + 3\cos n)^n} \le \frac{6^n}{7^n}. $$